# SVN Merge revisions into a single one

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created a new repository and added some things inside, now i have a huge list of revisions because of the addition. I wish to collapse all of the revisions into a single one, but I couldn't find a solution to this.

All I could find is merging branch with trunk.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This really doesn't make a lot of sense. Try rephrasing the question.

Comment: Do you mean branches rather than revisions?

Comment: I made 20 commits, shows as 20 commits, I want to stack them to 1. Perhaps I am not using the correct terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

You can't do it - history in Subversion is immutable

**Longer answer**

You can't do it easy and using only svn-client and single repo

**Long answer**

You have to create and use new repository, in which you'll store Revision 1 and (after handwork) state of the latest revision

*Draft of process*

- export (as unversioned tree) revision 1
- export into another location HEAD
- create new repo
- Import into it Rev1-tree
- Checkout into (new) WC new repository
- Update WC by files from HEAD-export (replace updated files, delete deleted, add added)
- Commit
- Delete all N-revisions repository

*Note*: Steps 1 and 4 can be

- Create dump of repo with revision 1 only
- Load dump from p.1